# Blender 2.92.0 Sphere is invisible when created

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Im just new to blender, I just downloaded blender, but when i add a sphere its invisible ive tried  googling help but none worked so here I am[image].

Comment: Re image are you confusing the sphere with the circle?. _`Add > Mesh > UVSphere`_

Comment: Also, you can choose whether to have the circle filled with faces when you create it :). There's a small dropdown bottom left.

Comment: Well . . . . . . .  That's embarrassing XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you added a circle - not a sphere. A circle is a 2D object, a sphere a 3D object.

To add a sphere press Shift-A -> Mesh -> UV Sphere